# Get multiple author in PDF using vb6

Tags: vb6

In VB6 I am using "AcroExch.PDDoc" getinfo("author") to access pdf meta. But it returns only one author but the PDF contains Two authors. How I get all the authors from PDF

Answer (score 0):

There is only one Author field in a PDF document. Presumably this is the one which is returned by .GetInfo("author"). I suspect that the other author is stored as a custom property, e.e. .GetInfo("author2"). Can you look at the custom properties collection for the document in Acrobat?